# Finder window does not remember size. Yosemite

Tags: finder, macos

Window Finder periodically receives the default size . I updated to Yosemite clean and updated, but it is repeated. Removes p.list, D_Store: sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \; contents of folders Preference, the result is 0 the error persists . Who has this bug , is there a solution? Thank you all .

Comment: Seems a general issue. For the record, I accomplish manage it with a combination of two apps moom (to set size an position) and keyboard maestro (to configure it per window).

Answer (score 2):

1. Do a backup in case you mess up. (For experienced users who understand what the next steps do, this can be skipped.)
2. Open the Finder
3. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enter `~/Library/Preferences/`. This will open the Preferences folder inside your personal library.
4. Find the file `com.apple.finder.plist` and move (drag) it to your desktop.
5. Re-launch the Finder: Click the Apple icon in the top left corner, select  `Force Quit`, select `Finder` and kill it. You can restart, but this is quicker.
6. If it works okay, delete the plist from the desktop. If not, return the .plist to where you got it from, overwriting the newer one.

This worked for me.

[Credits](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27026220#27026220)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question: You want Finder windows to be of a certain size even after closing them?

Try holding the option key while dragging to resize, then immediately after that close all finder windows, and relaunch.

Comment: Thank Zerohedge, no - it does not work.

Comment: OS X Yosemite. This does not work.